# Allow store scope attributes in Configurable Products

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-attribute

Is there any way to remove the requirement that only global attributes can be used to create configurable products?

I would like to use my store scope attributes to create configurable products.

I assume it is not just as easy as removing

```
$attribute->getIsGlobal() == \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL
```

From

```
public function canUseAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute $attribute)
```

Comment: I don't have solid proof to back this up, but I think that the full functionality of configurable products is based on the fact that the configurable attributes have global scope.